# How to return an HTTP 500 code on any error, no matter what

Tags: php, http, response

I'm writing an authentication script in PHP, to be called as an API, that needs to return 200`only in the case that it approves the request, and`403`(Forbidden) or`500` otherwise.

The problem I'm running into is that php returns `200` in the case of error conditions, outputting the error as html instead.  How can I make absolutely sure that php will return an HTTP `500` code unless I explicitly return the HTTP `200` or HTTP `403` myself?  In other words, I want to turn any and all warning or error conditions into `500`s, no exceptions, so that the default case is rejecting the authentication request, and the exception is approving it with a `200` code.

I've fiddled with `set_error_handler()` and `error_reporting()`, but so far no luck.  For example, if the code outputs something before I send the HTTP response code, PHP naturally reports that you can't modify header information after outputting anything.  However, this is reported by PHP as a `200` response code with html explaining the problem.  I need even this kind of thing to be turned into a `500` code.

Is this possible in PHP?  Or do I need to do this at a higher level like using `mod_rewrite` somehow?  If that's the case, any idea how I'd set that up?

Comment: There is a bug report for this here: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50921 – it seams like it may get fixed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I checked [the PHP docs for header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), and it's simpler than I was making it - if the second parameter is true, it will replace a similar header. the default is true. So the correct behavior is header `('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');`, then do the authentication logic, then if it authenticates, do header `('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')`. It will replace the 403 response, and will guarantee that 403 is the default.

Answer (score 86):

Simply send the status code as a response [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
```

Remember that when sending this there **must not** be any output before it. That means no `echo` calls and no HTML or whitespace.

Comment: Also remember that this won't work if running as CGI, or under IIS.

Comment: Thanks - I know how to send the response code, and I know not to send output before it, as I mentioned in my question.  My question is how to prevent PHP from sending a 200 response code with the error as html in the case of errors.

Comment: Send it then output the error message? Sending a status header tells PHP to override the default `200 OK` response code.

Comment: BoltClock: How would you know what header to send in case of unhandled exceptions?

Comment: @ThomasAhle 500 Internal Server Error is a reasonable choice :-) "Internal error"

Comment: Great solution, although all of the kids nowadays are using `http_response_code(500);` to set the header.

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks

Comment: Too bad Firefox, even on April 2017, still refuses to render its default error pages and prefer to show a totally blank page instead.

Comment: It is also possible to return an output. Just add `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` to your script.

Answer (score 20):

Since PHP 5.4.0 there is a specialized function:

```
<?php http_response_code( 500 ); ?>
```

Just make sure that it's called before any other output.

Reference:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: While nifty to know, this doesn't stop php from returning a 200 OK when it encounters an error.

Comment: sure, that's no replacement for error `handling`, it's error `reporting`

Answer (score 15):

On the php page for set_error_handler() you can find a comment by smp at ncoastsoft dot com posted on 08-Sep-2003 10:28 which exlpains how to even catch fatal errors (which you can normally not catch with a custom error handler. I changed the code for you needs:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

function fatal_error_handler($buffer) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit(0);
}

function handle_error ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit(0);
}

ob_start("fatal_error_handler");
set_error_handler("handle_error");

//would normally cause a fatal error, but instead our output handler will be called allowing us to handle the error.
somefunction();
ob_end_flush();
```

This shold catch the fatal error of the non existing function. It than returns a 500 and stops the execution of the rest of the script.

Comment: It will catch any error but parse errors. – also, it will hide the error trace, so you could just as well have disabled display_errors to get the same function.

Comment: @ThomasAhle you can output a stack trace yourself after you set the headers

Answer (score 6):

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 Forbidden');
```

You should not use 500, that indicates an internal server error.

This (and other headers) should be sent before any ouput, except if you have output buffering enabled.

Comment: Thank you, but that isn't my question.  I know how to send the response code.  How do I prevent PHP from sending the 200 code in the case of errors?

Comment: @Jake If send the 403 response, it won't send 200. Am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is that if it runs into an error condition before I know whether to send a 403 0r 200, it sends a 200 with the error.  I want the opposite behavior - I want the default in the case of an error to be 403 or 500 or pretty much anything other than 200, so that only I send a 200 response code.

I'll try writing the 403 code right away, and then overwriting that with a 200 if it succeeds.  I don't know what the behavior is supposed to be in this case though.  Does anyone know?  Will it correctly overwrite the 403?

Answer (score 2):

Curious if you ever figured out how to get PHP to return 500 on Parse errors... I have the same exact need... API is posting to our app and expects a 200 only if everything was processed correctly...

In the case of a Parse error, PHP returns an Error 200 and I have used both of these functions:

register_shutdown_function()
set_error_handler()

and these don't get hit when a "parse/syntax" error happens in the code...

So this is a low-level PHP function that would have to be set in the PHP.INI or somewhere... I am using PHP 5.3.10...

Answer (score 1):

Use output buffering to allow you to modify the headers after writing to the body of the page. You can set this in the [ini file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) rather than updating every script.

(Note the header() call will still fail if you explicitly flush the output buffer)

C.