# how to change Internal server error code in an php application?

Tags: php

In my PHP aplication,I want that whenever -Internal Server or 500 error occurs,I want the error code to be changed from 500 to 302.I mean error code 302.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  It will only confuse users.

Comment: You want to cure the symptom instead of fixing the cause? Don't!

Comment: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Comment: actuallly i am testing the application by appscan, and it advises us to change 500 error to 302. 500 error is a security breach error and it means that the ap can be hacked but 302 error is safe error in terms of app security. so th neeed to change the code

Answer (score 1):

Try to use http_response_code.Also, take a look on related question [How to return an HTTP 500 code on any error, no matter what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052715/how-to-return-an-http-500-code-on-any-error-no-matter-what).

Answer (score 0):

i would not recommend you do that.

Instead wrap your code that is generating this error within a Try & Catch statement and try to handle exception there.

```
try {
   // your code here
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: can u post the full code i mean if the error is 500 then the full code to handle that error 500

Comment: you will have to post the source code by editing your question which can help us understand why you have error code 500

Comment: 500 error is not aceptable by appscan which isa software to test for application security. 302 is aceptable thats y we need to change the eror code

Comment: you cannot expect an answer to your question without a source code, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: if we change the parameters passed in url to values like %27 then