# HTTP status header on PHP fatal error, code proposition

Tags: php

I was trying to figure out how to set HTTP status header to 500 if there was php fatal error (for handling AJAX requests).

Related question: [How can I get php to return 500 upon encountering a fatal exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1555862/1637178)

I don't want to use `register_shutdown_function` which in my opinion is not an elegant solution.

Is below code a good solution?

Will it always work for fatal errors?

I assume that application code has no output untill last `echo` call and there are no calls to `flush()` function (which after invocation prevents modifying headers).

```
<?php

set_status_code(500);

// ...
// (application code with no output)

// Application didn't crash up to this point,
// so we set http status code 200.
set_status_code(200);

echo $outputBuffer;
```

Is `flush()` the only function that breaks desired behaviour?

Comment: ..why would there be a fatal error?

Comment: Apache (or your webserver of choice) should return a 500 automatically if PHP crashes outright.

Comment: I prefer the style of returning a `success` and possibly `message` variables to the Javascript rather than it looking for the `500`.

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis because sometimes applications just crash and I wan't to handle this errors from JavaScript ajax requests.

Comment: @deceze On Apache (WAMP) somehow it doesn't give status 500. I've tried disabling php errors, but it still get status 200.

Comment: @deceze It was Xdebugs fault. After disabling it then it works ([related](http://codeblow.com/questions/steps-to-make-php-set-http-status-code-to-500-instantly-just/)).

Comment: I'd agree with @MrCode. I'd consider it bad practice to be setting an error 500 explicitly. A 500 error should be generated when you have a fatal server error -- ie the server software has crashed, or is misconfigured or is unable to run for some reason. It should not be used as an error code for software that has run without crashing. Like MrCode, I would prefer to use a response code within your Ajax response, but if you must use a HTTP response code, the 400-range error codes are more apprpriate than a 500 code.

Comment: @SDC I have stated that I want to handle FATAL errors.

Comment: if the program is still running, then the error is not fatal. By definition, if your program is able to set the http code, then code 500 is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you turn off PHP errors, Apache will give a 500 status code whenever a fatal PHP error occurs.

Comment: `<?php ini_set("display_errors", "off"); throw new Exception("lolwut");` does't give 500 status code on Apache. How do I make this work?

Comment: FireBug, Fiddler2. Ok, I figured this out. Xdebug was the problem (check [this](http://codeblow.com/questions/steps-to-make-php-set-http-status-code-to-500-instantly-just/) out). Thanks! :)

Comment: On PHP 5.4 Xdebug shows error 500 an works fine. Related: [php/xdebug bug](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=587).