# Set response code for compile errors in PHP

Tags: php, http, error-handling, httpresponse

PHP version 7.2

I would like the php endpoint to return a code 500 if the script fails to parse. Currently I get a code 200 with the response body:

```html
<br/>
<b>Parse error</b>
:  syntax error, unexpected 'felkdfle' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in <b>/var/www/html/api/logs.php</b>
on line <b>9</b>
<br/>
```

The front end will not handle this as an error because the response says its a success.

I tried this:

```php
// does not work because parse errors can not be caught within the script
function exception_handler(Throwable $exception) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}
set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

// also does not work
function fatal_handler() {
    http_response_code(500);
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo $error;
}
register_shutdown_function('fatal_handler');
```

So how can I set the response code php uses to respond after a parse error?

Comment: If the code can't be parsed, nothing runs, so you can't call functions to change the response code.

Comment: PHP normally returns a 500 error when there's a fatal error, not 200.

Comment: Is line 9 calling `eval()`?

Comment: As Barmar says, a 500 error is the default behaviour for uncaught errors, so it sounds like something else is intercepting and returning the 200. Also, you can catch parse errors (including with `set_exception_handler`) for any files you `include`/`require`, just not _the current file_.

Comment: If I not wrong, if the main called script is fine then it will continue, but if it any include or evaluate PHP has problem, then could generate this error. Also, it depends how the php.ini reporting error is configured. It could be configured to report errors on the client instead of only logs the errors on the server.

Comment: What web server software and PHP SAPI are you using to execute the code? I think the former is either not getting the error from the latter, or it's configured to ignore errors.

Comment: @Barmar this apparently is not the case for PHP version 7.2 ! I just tested it locally on my machine and it also returns 200 in the most basic setup. The new version returns 500.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug in PHP version 7.2, which we are using. I verified it on my local machine, the new version 8.4 returns 500 but the old version 7.2 returns 200

Edit: Bug may be overdramatic, it seems like a different default configuration. Apparently 7.2 uses display_errors = on by default (at least it behaves that way by default) and 8.3 has them off. Thats why 7.2 sends a 200 code when it logs the error to the browser. With an ini file setting display_errors = off it also returns the expected 500.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427754/285587

Comment: @YourCommonSense that is not the same issue. This here is not about handling exceptions but about when the very script fails to parse. I tried setting the response header obviously but it defaults to 200 when a parse error is encountered, at least on version 7.2.

Comment: Please read the **actual answer linked** not the top one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The answer you linked to calls `ini_set()`. You can't call functions if the script doesn't parse.

Comment: @Barmar the answer **literally says "Standard PHP configuration does return 500 when error occurs!**" which is the exact answer to this question. While using  ini_set **only for demonstration** It also explains that this answer is **totally wrong**, and PHP version has nothing to do with this behavior.

Comment: @YourCommonSense That answer was written in 2016. PHP 7.2 was released in 2017. So how could they have known about this bug?

Comment: @Barmar WE could know this is not a bug :) The op provides an HTML error message which clearly indicates that display errors was turned ON. Which is the actual reason, why there was no 500 status.

Comment: Display errors was probably turned on in the init file, not the code. @YourCommonSense

Comment: @Barmar whatever. Still this answer is wrong and the linked answer is correct.

Comment: @YourCommonSense so I checked and 8.3 does return 500 with no error message in the response if I do not link it to the .ini file. However if I link it to an ini file, even if it is empty, it also returns the error in a 200 response. The 7.2 version does this both with and without ini file. I could not get 8.3 to return 500 with the ini file yet, even with `display_errors = off`

Comment: @YourCommonSense okay the behaviour is really weird. Apparently the 8.3 did not really find the ini file, me passing -c dir/ just made it override it default config but it didnt find dir/config.ini now I passed it the path to the file with `display_errors = off` and now it returns 500 even with the custom config and 7.2 does so too. Unfortunately now the error is not sent in the response anymore. I want to to send the error message in a 500 response. Is that possible at all?

Comment: This is not how it's usually done. Internal errors are not for sending anywhere. log_errors=1 should have them logged and this is where you find them. Or you could possibly give a full picture and explain why do you need an internal PHP error message for a client and how it should help.

Comment: @YourCommonSense okay, maybe it is not worth it, but since the browser usually logs all the other errors it would be nice if the error message also showed up there. It is not really needed to tho. The main thing is that the backend sends code 500 when the compilation fails, which now works with display_errors = off.

Comment: @stimulate mind you it would be a VERY rare occasion to have a syntax error in a bootstrap file. In all other cases, every fatal error could be accompanied with a generic error message, like "Internal server error" if you really need something like that.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I think the main issue is that the php runs on an embedded device or some docker container and its kind of difficult to get the direct stdout for the message and I am not sure if we have log files configured. Might be worth doing it though.